# Element API: How to get entries up to a certain page?

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, elementquery

I have a query that is pulling entries from a structure with 
`elementsPerPage' => 3`

If my pagination looks like this:

```
Page 1:
Entries: A, B, C

Page 2:
Entries: D, E, F

Page 3:
Entries: G, H, I
```

How should I write the query to get all entries up to page 2?

```
Request Page 2 Results:

Entries: A, B, C, D, E, F

Request Page 3 Results:

Entries: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tweet shows a way to adjust the elements per page dynamically with a query string param -> https://twitter.com/JakeDohm/status/1157305040278839296?s=20 so you could just request 6 or 9 items to get the same result.